# Java String.format adding spaces to integers

Tags: java

I have a small piece of code that i don't understand the output.

This output is adding spaces to my string format text. I'm doing something wrong?

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int a1 = 540;
        int a2 = 492;
        int a3 = 200;
        int a4 = 500;
        int a5 = 600;
        String a = "/share.html?title=%1s&description=%2s&image=%3s&width=%4s&height=%5s";
        String b = String.format(a, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
        System.out.println(b);
     }
}
```

The output is:

```
/share.html?title=540&description=492&image=200&width= 500&height=  600
```

Why there are those spaces on the last width and height?

Comment: I think you mean `%1$s`,  `%2$s`,  `%3$s`,  `%4$s` etc. Or simply `%s`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the numbers from your format specifiers:

```
String a = "/share.html?title=%s&description=%s&image=%s&width=%s&height=%s";
```

Using a numerical value inside the format specifier like you did, you are specifying the **minimal width** of the output - this is the reason why you do not see any spaces for your first three values.

If you want to reference a particular parameter instead of letting the formatter evaluate them in the order they are specified, you can specify an argument index in the form `n$` where n is the index of the referenced parameter (like `1$`, `2$`, ...).

See also [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more information.

Instead of `%s`, you could also specify `%d` since all your arguments are of type `int`.

Comment: "Java's Formatter does not use position identifiers to reference the respective parameters" By default, yes. But you can specify the argument index.

Comment: You should also suggest changing to `%d`, since the values are `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you add Strings with lenght 4 and 5 and your values are ony 3 char.

You shoud use `%d` for formatting decimal.

The number in front of `s` is the length not the Position.

Answer (score 2):

The [general structure of the format specifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) is

```
%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
```

If you're trying to refer to argument indexes, you need a `$` after the number, e.g.:

```
height=%5$s
```

However, since you're only using the parameters once, and in order, you can simply use:

```
height=%s
```

Answer (score 1):

`%4s` means there should be total 4 characters outputted. And your number has 3 characters. So, it displays one `" "`. So, you need to remove all the numbers from format string.

Comment: Not "total", but "at least".

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        int a1 = 540;
        int a2 = 492;
        int a3 = 200;
        int a4 = 500;
        int a5 = 600;
        String a = "/share.html?title=%s&description=%s&image=%s&width=%s&height=%s";
        String b = String.format(a, a1, a2, a3,a4,a5);
        System.out.println(b);
```

let me know if it works