# JScrollPane Not Appearing

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jframe, window

I have looked at many of the other threads that are related to this, however none of the suggested fixes worked.
I have tried doing `contentPanel.revalidate();` and `contentPanel.repaint();`, after adding it. I have tried adding both the JScrollPane and JTextArea to the contentPanel, and I have tried individually. I have tried changing from a JTextArea to a JTextPane, however none of that worked. The JTextArea shows up fine without the JScrollPane, but when I add it, the JTextArea completely disappears.
I am using a null layout, and I think that could be the issue, but if there is a solution that doesn't involve changing the layout, I would much prefer that. If there is no way to fix it other that changing the layout, please let me know. Thanks.

Here is the code (It is a JDialog window that is a popup off of the main window):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TransactionsDialog extends JDialog
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6939141004692809959L;
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    private JTextArea txtTransactions;
    private JComboBox<String> comboStartMonth;
    private JComboBox<Integer> comboStartDay;
    private JComboBox<Integer> comboStartYear;
    private JComboBox<String> comboEndMonth;
    private JComboBox<Integer> comboEndDay;
    private JComboBox<Integer> comboEndYear;
    private JCheckBox chckbxStartDate;
    private JCheckBox chckbxEndDate;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public TransactionsDialog(BankAccount account)
    {
        setResizable(false);
        /**
         * Populating (Day, Month, Year) Arrays.
         */
        ArrayList<String> monthList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int month = 0; month < 12; month++)
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            String monthName = monthDate.format(calendar.getTime());

            monthList.add(monthName);
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> dayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int day = 1; day <= 31; day++)
        {
            dayList.add(day);
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> yearList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int year = 1980; year <= Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR); year++)
        {
            yearList.add(year);
        }

        setTitle("Transactions of " + account);
        setBounds(100, 100, 404, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        comboStartMonth = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboStartMonth.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        comboStartMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(monthList.toArray(new String[monthList.size()])));
        comboStartMonth.setEnabled(false);
        comboStartMonth.setBounds(100, 8, 118, 20);
        contentPanel.add(comboStartMonth);

        comboStartDay = new JComboBox<Integer>();
        comboStartDay.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(dayList.toArray(new Integer[dayList.size()])));
        comboStartDay.setEnabled(false);
        comboStartDay.setBounds(228, 8, 71, 20);
        comboStartDay.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(comboStartDay);

        comboStartYear = new JComboBox<Integer>();
        comboStartYear.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(yearList.toArray(new Integer[yearList.size()])));
        comboStartYear.setSelectedIndex(comboStartYear.getItemCount() - 1);
        comboStartYear.setEnabled(false);
        comboStartYear.setBounds(309, 8, 71, 20);
        comboStartYear.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(comboStartYear);

        comboEndMonth = new JComboBox<String>();
        comboEndMonth.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(monthList.toArray(new String[monthList.size()])));
        comboEndMonth.setEnabled(false);
        comboEndMonth.setBounds(100, 34, 119, 20);
        comboEndMonth.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(comboEndMonth);

        comboEndDay = new JComboBox<Integer>();
        comboEndDay.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(dayList.toArray(new Integer[dayList.size()])));
        comboEndDay.setEnabled(false);
        comboEndDay.setBounds(228, 34, 71, 20);
        comboEndDay.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(comboEndDay);

        comboEndYear = new JComboBox<Integer>();
        comboEndYear.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<Integer>(yearList.toArray(new Integer[yearList.size()])));
        comboEndYear.setSelectedIndex(comboEndYear.getItemCount() - 1);
        comboEndYear.setEnabled(false);
        comboEndYear.setBounds(309, 34, 71, 20);
        comboEndYear.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(comboEndYear);

        txtTransactions = new JTextArea();
        txtTransactions.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        txtTransactions.setEditable(false);
        txtTransactions.setBounds(10, 63, 368, 187);

        JScrollPane txtTScrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtTransactions);
        contentPanel.add(txtTScrollPane);
        contentPanel.revalidate();
        contentPanel.repaint();

        chckbxStartDate = new JCheckBox("Start Date:");
        chckbxStartDate.setBounds(6, 7, 89, 23);
        chckbxStartDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(chckbxStartDate.isSelected())
                {
                    comboStartMonth.setEnabled(true);
                    comboStartDay.setEnabled(true);
                    comboStartYear.setEnabled(true);            
                }
                else
                {
                    comboStartMonth.setEnabled(false);
                    comboStartDay.setEnabled(false);
                    comboStartYear.setEnabled(false);
                }

                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(chckbxStartDate);

        chckbxEndDate = new JCheckBox("End Date:");
        chckbxEndDate.setBounds(6, 33, 89, 23);
        chckbxEndDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(chckbxEndDate.isSelected())
                {
                    comboEndMonth.setEnabled(true);
                    comboEndDay.setEnabled(true);
                    comboEndYear.setEnabled(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    comboEndMonth.setEnabled(false);
                    comboEndDay.setEnabled(false);
                    comboEndYear.setEnabled(false);
                }

                listTransactions(account);
            }
        });
        contentPanel.add(chckbxEndDate);

        listTransactions(account);
    }

    private void listTransactions(BankAccount account)
    {       
        LocalDateTime startTime;
        LocalDateTime endTime;
        String startMonthName = (String) comboStartMonth.getSelectedItem();
        int startDay = (int) comboStartDay.getSelectedItem();
        int startYear = (int) comboStartYear.getSelectedItem();
        String endMonthName = (String) comboEndMonth.getSelectedItem();
        int endDay = (int) comboEndDay.getSelectedItem();
        int endYear = (int) comboEndYear.getSelectedItem();

        if(chckbxStartDate.isSelected())
        {
            int startMonth = Month.valueOf(startMonthName.toUpperCase()).getValue();    

            try
            {
                startTime = LocalDateTime.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay, 0, 0);
            }
            catch(DateTimeException e)
            {
                txtTransactions.setText("INVALID DATE");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            startTime = null;
        }

        if(chckbxEndDate.isSelected())
        {
            int endMonth = Month.valueOf(endMonthName.toUpperCase()).getValue();

            try
            {
                endTime = LocalDateTime.of(endYear, endMonth, endDay, 23, 59);
            }
            catch(DateTimeException e)
            {
                txtTransactions.setText("INVALID DATE");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            endTime = null;
        }

        ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = account.getTransactions(startTime, endTime);
        String output = "";
        int maxAmountDigits = 1;

        for(Transaction t : transactionList)
        {
            String stringAmount = String.format("%.2f", t.getAmount());

            if(stringAmount.length() > maxAmountDigits)
                maxAmountDigits = stringAmount.length();
        }

        output += String.format("%-10s %-8s %-" + (maxAmountDigits + 1) + "s %s\n", "Date", "Time", "Amount", "Description");   
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791455/java-string-format-adding-spaces-to-integers
        output += String.format("%0" + 100 + "d\n", 0).replace("0", "-");

        for(Transaction t : transactionList)
        {
            output += String.format("%d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%02d $%-" + maxAmountDigits + ".2f %s\n", t.getTransactionTime().getYear(),
                                                                                                      t.getTransactionTime().getMonthValue(),
                                                                                                      t.getTransactionTime().getDayOfMonth(),
                                                                                                      t.getTransactionTime().getHour(),
                                                                                                      t.getTransactionTime().getMinute(),
                                                                                                      t.getTransactionTime().getSecond(),
                                                                                                      t.getAmount(),
                                                                                                      t.getDescription());
        }

        txtTransactions.setText(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: `setLayout(null)` is the first rookie mistake - you’ve failed to understand the importance of layout managers and failed to take over their responsibility correctly. Calling `revalidate` is pointless as it triggers a new layout pass, but since you’re not using a layout manager, it won’t do anything. Simple answer - use one or more appropriate layout managers

Comment: Yes, you were correct. The null layout was the mistake I made, and after changing it to a different layout (Grid Bag Layout), there were no issues in creating the JScrollPane. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.  Your question has been rolled back to its previous state. For more information, please visit the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contentPanel.setLayout(null);
```

First you set the layout to null:

```
    JScrollPane txtTScrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtTransactions);
    contentPanel.add(txtTScrollPane);
    //contentPanel.revalidate();
    //contentPanel.repaint();
```

Then you add the scrollpane to the content panel. However, you didn't use setBounds() on the scrollpane and the default size of a component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

However, the solution is not to add the setBounds(...). The solution is to not use a null layout. It may seem easier with a null layout but then you get into problems like this and components don't work properly when used in a scrollpane.

So the proper solution is to fix your code and use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Then the layout manager will set the size and location of the component so you don't have to worry about it.

The revalidate() and repaint() is only used when adding components to a visible GUI to invoke the layout manager so they are not needed.

Also when creating the text area do something like:

```
//txtTransactions = new JTextArea();
txtTransactions = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

This will let the text area determine its own preferred size based on the rows/columns and font of the text area. Then the layout manager can do a better job.

Comment: Thank you for the input. What layout would you suggest I use. Also, other than the null layout, which layouts should I  avoid?

Comment: I have no idea what you want your layout do look like so I can't suggest what layout manager to use. In many cases you don't use a single layout. Instead you will logically group components on child panels with different layout mangers to achiever your desired layout. I gave you the tutorial link so you can download and play with the examples to see how they each work.

Comment: After using a Grid Bag Layout, I was able to successfully get the JScrollPane working with no issues. Thank you for your valuable help.